# Using .Net remoting with ipv6

Tags: .net, remoting, ipv6

I am using `Activator.CreateInstance(type, "http://localhost/blah")` to invoke a service using remoting in .Net 3.5 on Windows 7.

As far as I understand it, Windows 7 will use IPv6 by default (certainly if I ping localhost it resolves as ::1) so I would expect this URL to make an IPv6 connection, but in my tests, it always connects as IPv4

How do I specify in the remoting URL that I want to use IPv6?

Comment: Maybe trying to disable IPv4 on your network card and see whether it now uses IPv6? (Just as a proof to see whether it is possible to use V6 at all, not as the final solution).

Comment: I'm back looking at this one again. I've found that using http://[::1]/ will use IPv6, so I know there's nothing in remoting itself that is disabling IPv6. it seems to be just something funny in the name lookup. But ping and web browsers will resolve the same host names as IPv6 as expected

Answer (score 2):

This happens because .net remoting server by default listens on IPv4. If your network is configured to use both IPv6 and IPv4, Windows 7 will resolve hostname first as IPv6 and then as IPv4, which is default address on which remoting server listens.

So in order to use IPv6 URL, you must setup remoting server to listen also on IPv6. If you are using app.config do this:

```
<system.runtime.remoting>
  <application>
    <service>
      <wellknown mode="Singleton" type="MyApplication.MyServer, MyAssembly" objectUri="MyServer" />
    </service>
    <channels>
      <channel ref="tcp" name="tcp6" port="9000" bindTo="[::]" />
      <channel ref="tcp" name="tcp4" port="9000" bindTo="0.0.0.0" />
    </channels>
  </application>
</system.runtime.remoting>
```

Or to configure programmatically:

```
IDictionary properties = new Hashtable();
properties["name"] = "tcp6";
properties["port"] = 9000;
properties["bindTo"] = "[::]";
TcpServerChannel channel = new TcpServerChannel(properties, null);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel,  false);
```

For more info see [this blog post](http://www.ookii.org/Blog/net_remoting_and_ipv6).